# SAP UI5 RadioButtonGroup if selected

Tags: controller, radio-button, conditional-statements, sapui5

I'm currently trying to implement a routing with condition with UI5...

This is my view.xml:

```
        <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
            <RadioButtonGroup id="bgroup" columns="2" class="sapUiMediumMarginBottom">
                <buttons>
                    <RadioButton id="RB1" text="start with segmentation"/>
                    <RadioButton id="RB2" text="start with target group"/>
                </buttons>
            </RadioButtonGroup>
        </VBox>

        <m:HBox>
            <m:items>
                <m:StandardTile title="End-of-Warranty" infoState="None" icon="sap-icon://car-rental" press="_onStandardTilePress"/>
                <m:StandardTile title="End-of-Leasing" infoState="None" icon="sap-icon://car-rental"/>
            </m:items>
            <m:layoutData/>
        </m:HBox>
```

That's what my .js file is looking right now:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
     "use strict";

     return Controller.extend("wizard.controller.page1", {

         _onStandardTilePress: function (oEvent) {
             var oapp = sap.ui.getCore().byId("dcw");

         oapp.to("idpage2");
         }
     });
     }
)
```

At the moment, it's just navigating to idpage2 if you click StandardTile End-of-Warranty. The RadioButtons are not recoginzed, no condition.

What I want to do: only navigate to idpage2 if RadioButton with id RB1 is selected. If RB2 is selected, navigate to idpage3.

Any idea? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the "selected" property of the RadioButtons before define where to navigate. Use getSelected() function:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.RadioButton.html#getSelected

Here a snippet with the info you have provided:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>MVC with XmlView</title>

  <!-- Load UI5, select "blue crystal" theme and the "sap.m" control library -->
  <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
   src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
   data-sap-ui-theme='sap_belize_plus'
   data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'
   data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax='complex'></script>


  <!-- DEFINE RE-USE COMPONENTS - NORMALLY DONE IN SEPARATE FILES -->

  <!-- define a new (simple) View type as an XmlView
   - using data binding for the Button text
   - binding a controller method to the Button's "press" event
   - also mixing in some plain HTML
   note: typically this would be a standalone file -->

  <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="my.own.controller">
          <App id="dcw">
            <pages>
              <Page id="idpage1">
              <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
                  <RadioButtonGroup id="bgroup" columns="2" class="sapUiMediumMarginBottom">
                      <buttons>
                          <RadioButton id="RB1" text="start with segmentation"/>
                          <RadioButton id="RB2" text="start with target group"/>
                      </buttons>
                  </RadioButtonGroup>
              </VBox>

              <HBox>
                  <items>
                      <StandardTile title="End-of-Warranty" infoState="None" icon="sap-icon://car-rental" press="_onStandardTilePress"/>
                      <StandardTile title="End-of-Leasing" infoState="None" icon="sap-icon://car-rental"  press="_onStandardTilePress"/>
                  </items>
                  <layoutData/>
              </HBox>
              </Page>
              <Page id="idpage2" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="onNavBack">
                  <ObjectHeader title="Page2 - start with segmentation"/>
              </Page>
              <Page id="idpage3" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="onNavBack">
                  <ObjectHeader title="Page3 - start with target group"/>
              </Page>
            </pages>
          </App>
  </mvc:View> 
        </script>


  <script>
   // define a new (simple) Controller type
   sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {
              
              
    _onStandardTilePress: function (oEvent) {
                    var oapp = this.getView().byId("dcw");
                      
                    if(this.getView().byId("RB1").getSelected()){
                       oapp.to(this.getView().byId("idpage2"));
                    }
                    else if(this.getView().byId("RB2").getSelected()){
                       oapp.to(this.getView().byId("idpage3"));
                    }
                 },
              
                onNavBack: function(oEvent){
                    oEvent.getSource().getParent().back();
                }
   });
 
   // instantiate the View
   var myView = sap.ui.xmlview({viewContent:jQuery('#view1').html()}); // accessing the HTML inside the script tag above
  
   myView.placeAt('content');
  </script>
 
 </head>
 <body id='content' class='sapUiBody'>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great!! good to hear it!! You can mark it as solution so it will be easier to find the solution for others with the same porblem